# Swift Timer is resetting second's value

Tags: swift, uitableview, timer

I have a TableViewCell which has a timer object inside. I'm having an issue where when a new TableViewCell is created all previous TableViewCell timers have their second's value reset to 00. What's strange is the hour and minute remain unaffected. Here's the code inside the cell.

```
var stopwatch: DispatchSourceTimer?
var expires: Date?

func setup(with timer: MapTimer) {
    
    stopwatch = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: .main)
    stopwatch?.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: 1.0)
    
    let date = Date()
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.setValue(timer.hour, for: .hour)
    components.setValue(timer.min, for: .minute)
    expires = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: date)
    
    stopwatch?.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
        self?.countDownTimer()
    }
    
    stopwatch?.resume()
    
}

@objc fileprivate func countDownTimer() {

    let timeLeft        = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: Date(), to: expires!)
    let hourFormatted   = timeLeft.hour! > 9 ? "\(timeLeft.hour!)" : "0\(timeLeft.hour!)"
    let minFormatted    = timeLeft.minute! > 9 ? "\(timeLeft.minute!)" : "0\(timeLeft.minute!)"
    timerTime.text      = "\(hourFormatted):\(minFormatted):\(timeLeft.second!)"
    
    if timeLeft.hour! == 00 && timeLeft.minute! == 00 && timeLeft.second! <= 29 {
        timerTime.textColor = UIColor(named: "Red") ?? .red
    } else {
        timerTime.textColor = .white
    }
    
    if timeLeft.hour! == 00 && timeLeft.minute! == 00 && timeLeft.second! == 00 {
        stopwatch?.cancel()
        stopwatch = nil
    }

}
```

Am I missing something on the cell itself or is it the timer?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using var timer = Timer(),  instead of var stopwatch: DispatchSourceTimer?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I need guaranteed timers and you can't have that using TImer. Timer also doesn't support state-based pausing, only invalidating.

Comment: interesting, so, Timer.scheduledTimer() is not guaranteed? Also, there is a way to create a "pause" while using Timer() perhaps that will help

Comment: No, they aren't guaranteed to execute on the TimeInterval and frequency that you specify, especially when you need a certain level of accuracy. A standard Timer could execute on 1 second the first iteration, 1.06 the next, 1.103 etc. They're fine for simple apps that don't require much grunt work. For my issue I require Dispatch.

Comment: Im going to have to do some reading now. Thanks ! this was helpful for me haha